# How to delete a row from SQL table using button

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to write a function using php and javascript to delete a row from sql database when a button is clicked in that row. This is my table, so once you click the button in a specific row, it would remove said row using the login_id, but I can't really find a way to get this done.

```
                        '<td>' . $row['login_id'] . '</td>' .
                        '<td>' . $row['first_name'] . '</td>' .
                        '<td>' . $row['last_name'] . '</td>' .
                        '<td>' . $row['email'] . '</td>' .
                        '<td>' . $row['password'] . '</td>' .
                        '<td>' . $row['is_banned'] . '</td>' .                    
                        '<td>  <button type="button" name="deletebutton" onclick="deletefunction()">Delete</button>  </td>' .
                     '<tr>';
```

[this is what the table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5dHi.png)

Comment: `deletefunction()` needs a parameter that tells it which row to delete, like `onclick="deletefunction(' . $row['ID'] . ')"`. Then you make an AJAX call to PHP with the ID as a parameter.

Comment: The above comment is correct. Note that the Frontend code only sends a request to the server to delete that SQL data. Never manipulate SQL data from the FE, never. Send a network request for a dedicated API endpoint (assuming you have a REST API) to do the job.
Also I would suggest to use the browsers fetch API to do it. AJAX is old, complex and should not be used anymore.

Comment: @ChrissiGrilus how would i be able to do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @user18625843 Well where are you stuck with what was suggested? There are severa steps mentioned, each of which is quite researchable. It's not really clear what your exact problem is.